# Trigonometric polynomials are spanned by ${e^{inx}}$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

Are the trigonometric polynomials, namely, those having the domain $[a,b] \in \mathbb{R}$, and the range $\mathbb{C}$, spanned by the orthogonal vectors $e^{inx}$? I think this is assumed in the text I'm looking at, Fourier Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi, but I don't know how to show this. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: \begin{align}
\cos nx &= \frac12\left(e^{inx}+e^{-inx}\right)\\
\sin nx &= \frac1{2i}\left(e^{inx}-e^{-inx}\right)\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are, because $e^{it}-e^{-it}=2i\sin t $ and $e^{it}+e^{-it}=2\cos t$.